# Question on converting grades

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Similiar in scheme to this question [How to convert from one grading scheme to another?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9058/how-to-convert-from-one-grading-scheme-to-another)

Do we need/want a big list question with an answer for each country explaining the dominant grading system used. While I think that one cannot directly convert grades, I think it is useful to roughly know what different grades mean. I think the universal converter is something like percentage of the class that gets a particular grade.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there really is a "universal conversion" available.

Besides, there is also this [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_%28education%29) on grading schemes in different nations. I don't think we need to reinvent the wheel.